# How do I create a React Component Library styled with Tailwind, and make the consuming project change its Theme Configuration?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, npm, tailwind-css

I am creating an internal component library and the styling solution is Tailwind. However, I wonder how would the consuming project apply its own styles to the components?

I have read the documentation and I have not found very good pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you. You can come up with a unified API to change your component styles.

The easiest way is to accept the `className` prop and attach that `className` to your component.

Consumers can fine-tune separate components or global styles, changing global TailWind CSS variables.

Comment: Yes. This seems correct. However, my question is more about "merging" or making both `tailwind.config.js` work together nicely.